# How can I configure my firewall to work with Docker?

Tags: networking, firewall, docker, network-bridge

My computer is hosting an application on port 1234 that should never be accessible from anything but my machine. However, my Docker container (which is running Apache) should be able to access this. Similarly, my Docker container is hosting a number of resources on various ports that should similarly be only accessible from my computer. Now, this is further complicated by the fact that my system uses a bridge for that specific network:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
4d4b5e752963        bridge              bridge              local               
c387eb42698a        project_default     bridge              local               
6818c0eb94bf        host                host                local               
f7e4ed6c05a2        none                null                local
```

This bridge (annoyingly) always has a randomly generated ID that changes each time I restart my Docker Compose setup:

```
br-c387eb42698a Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:29:95:fd:2c  
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:29ff:fe95:fd2c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:405753 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:530699 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:85147217 (85.1 MB)  TX bytes:75260996 (75.2 MB)
```

In short, I need the following:

- *Any* host  on `br-c387eb42698a` (or whatever the network name is) to access port 1234 on my local machine (conveniently 172.18.0.1)
- My machine to be able to access *any* port on *any* host on that subnet. (default)
- The world to never be able to access *any* port from the subnet *or* port 1234.

Ideally, a solution here would work in an IP-agnostic way such that it does not depend on the bridge being on the `172.18.0.0/24` subnet, nor would it break or allow data leaks if I'm connected to a network that happens to contain the `172.18.0.0/24` subnet.

The easiest thing I can think of would be to use the interface name and set up UFW rules around that, but I can't really do that as my interface is constantly changing.

How can I do this? While I'd prefer to do this in pure `ufw` (or `iptables` if necessary), I'm open to solutions that entail configuring Docker to always assign a persistent ID (or even custom name?) to the bridge interface.

Comment: How are you initializing/restarting the container to set up the bridge?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I'm using Docker Compose being called by a systemd service.

Comment: Ok. I was looking at [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/build-bridges/) and it mentions a bridge option that you can pass to docker. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Thanks for the help, I found something based on what you sent that seems to work for now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not possible in vanilla UFW because of the fact that the interface name is in a constant state of unguessability. In order to set something like this up, a manually defined network should be created. In short, one can use the [driver options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#bridge-driver-options) of Docker's `bridge` in the compose config to create a [custom network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specifying-custom-networks). This will look something like:

```
networks:
    my_bridge:
        driver: bridge
        driver_opts:
            com.docker.network.bridge.name: my-bridge
```

From here, the bridge config can be added to each service in the compose file:

```
myimage:
    image: myimage:1.0
    ports:
        - "2580:2580"
    networks:
        - my_bridge
```

Then, upon next start of the Compose system, the new network will be created with the proper name:

```
my-bridge Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 11:22:33:44:55:66  
      inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:1122:3344:5566/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:788 (788.0 B)  TX bytes:695 (695.0 B)
```

From there, adding UFW rules to allow connection to port 1234 are trivial:

```
ufw allow in on my-bridge from any to any port 1234
```

And suddenly, everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

To integrate the accepted answer, you can also use a docker command to create the network outside of docker-compose:

```
sudo docker network create -d bridge -o com.docker.network.bridge.name=my-bridge my_bridge
```

After that you can inspect the networks issuing

```
ip link show
```

Now, in your compose files you can just re-route the default network or define any network you like remapping it to the already existing one

```
version: "3"
services:
  test:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my_bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend the accepted answer further, when using Docker Swarm and deploying a stack, a `bridge` network is an invalid network type.

You can expect an error similar to the following:

`failed to create service [service_name]: Error response from daemon: The network [network_name] cannot be used with services. Only networks scoped to the swarm can be used, such as those created with the overlay driver.`

To allow a container to communicate with the host from a swarm cluster:

1. Create an `overlay` network

```yaml
services:
  my_service:
    #...
    networks:
      - my_bridge

networks:
    my_bridge:
        driver: overlay
```

2. enable communication with the network on the host:

```shell
# Docker creates a docker_gwbridge network in swarm mode for interaction with the host
$ ufw allow in on docker_gwbridge from any \
  to any port 12345 proto tcp
```

The service seems to be able to send messages to the the host via `172.17.0.1` and `172.18.0.1`